# SCP server for windows server 2003

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, scp

Is there any SCP server implementation for windows server 2003? 
My use case is to get files from windows server 2003 machine using SCP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [OpenSSH](http://openssh.com/) (or some other SSH implementation)

Comment: Does IIS FTP server, provided in windows installations provide that?

Comment: IIS won't include OpenSSH by default simply because of license incompatibilities.  It is entirely possible that Microsoft has included their own-rolled rendition of ssh.  Also, please DO NOT confuse FTP with SCP or SFTP.  They are *NOT* the same and FTP needs to [die a horrible death](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/FtpMustDie).